# How do I change the responses of a component in a ngFor addition to a Select, keep the others visible?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular8

When you select the item 'title' it is to hide the input. But when I select another item from another ngFor index, the selected input 'title' reappears.

[image: On select 'title' show item selected frist.]

```
<select class="form-control col-sm-6" 
     id="groupField{{i}}" 
     name="groupField{{i}}" 
     [(ngModel)]="selectedGroupingFields[i]" 
     (ngModelChange)="changeValue($event, i)">

<option [ngValue]="i+'_'+field.id" 
     *ngFor="let field of columnDefinitions">{{field.name}}</option>
</select>
```

[Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/component-angular-select-change)

Comment: what the problem in my question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<option [ngValue]="i+'_'+field.id" *ngFor="let field of columnDefinitions">{{field.name}}</option>
```

The problem is that the option doesn't have anunique id

Comment: Thx, really missing the index but still keeps changing when you select another item from another index